# Bound on large extra dimensions using gravitational waves

Tags: gravitational-waves, spacetime-dimensions, ligo, fine-tuning

Are there proposed observations using gravitational waves which put a bound on the size of large extra dimensions (say in the context of ADD model)? The claim in [the ADD paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9803315) is that you cannot gravitationally detect large extra dimensions if they are of the order $0.1$ mm or less. In such a case, can the effect of these extra dimensions (say more polarizations/flux leaking into extra dimensions etc.) be observed using the present-day LIGO (or using its upcoming cousins in near future) to set a bound on the size of the dimensions?

Comment: look at this where the limit for a specific model is given in microns https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06964